# Android SharedPreferences issue

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I need a little help with Android Shared Preferences. I'm trying to put a boolean type in SP and make it visible from every other activity in my application.And I want to be able to change the state of boolean type to true/false from another activity so I can make some changes in the UI depending on that boolean value.
For now I'm using this piece of code,which I understand but it's not correct.

Here it is :

Activity 1:

```
boolean isLoggedIn = false;

        SharedPreferences isLogged = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = isLogged.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("isLoggedIn", isLoggedIn);
        editor.commit();
```

Activity 2 :

```
        boolean isLogged=true;

        int mode = Activity.MODE_PRIVATE;
        SharedPreferences  mySharedPreferences;
        mySharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("isLoggedIn",mode);
        mySharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", isLogged);
        boolean bool = mySharedPreferences.getBoolean("isLoggedIn",false);

        Log.w("Boolean","Boolean state : "+bool);
```

Comment: is my solution is not working for you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Activity 2 try using like this and it will work

```
mySharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

and remove below line

```
mySharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", isLogged);
```

Comment: ingsaurabh is right. You got now 2 different preference storages, default and isLoggedIn.

Answer (score 0):

Put **edit.commit();** after **mySharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn", isLogged);**
This will help you to get correct value.